# USB Ethernet adapter randomly disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, usb, ethernet

USB Ethernet adapter randomly disconnecting and reconnecting

I have a USB adapter that works well on a windows machine, but I tried everything to make it work well on Linux.

It disconnects, but the adapter is still showing in `lsusb`, here is what shows on `dmesg` when it disconnect it doesn't show anything.

```
[18 11:52:52 2021] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[18 11:52:52 2021] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0fe6, idProduct=9900, bcdDevice=20.00
[18 11:52:52 2021] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[18 11:52:52 2021] usb 1-1: Product: 10/100M LAN
[18 11:52:52 2021] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: CoreChips
[18 11:52:52 2021] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 00E0813236ED
[18 11:52:52 2021] cdc_ether 1-1:2.0 eth0: register 'cdc_ether' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, CDC Ethernet Device, 00:e0:81:32:36:ed
```

I do not use TLP so it can't be TLP making it auto suspend.

I tried adding this to a file under `/etc/udev/rules`, but I don't know how to check if this config is working:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fe6", ATTR{idProduct}=="9900", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/con>
KERNEL=="cpu",RUN+="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n 1 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo'"
```

Also I added the `autosuspend` parameter on usbcore to `-1` and still doesn't done any improve to the situation.

I don't know if is really something with auto suspend or some other cause, but it seems be pretty stable while I'm not playing anything online.

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, please help :/

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem was with the wifi on while I used the ethernet usb connection, just turning it off solved my problem.